# Can someone cast Gust Of Wind Upwards, if someone is within 10 feet of them?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spell simply says, any direction emanating from you in a line 60 feet long and 10 feet wide. Up is a direction. If I were to cast Gust of wind upwards on say an enemy, would they be lifted in the air? How would their movement speed be affected? Would they take fall damage?

Comment: How is the enemy above you in the first place? That would be a big factor in the question of fall damage and movement.

Comment: @MivaScott I think the asker's imagining that the spell may allow the caster to emanate a 60-ft.-long, 10-ft.-wide line that's composed of wind that's blowing upward (or, really, any direction). However, the asker can correct me if I've misunderstood.

Comment: @HeyICanChan, I understand the intent, but it would be helpful to know the circumstances. Do they envision the person above them free falling, leaping down, levitating, flying, _Misty Step_, in gaseous form....Each situation could be its own answer. Maybe the caster is on the floor dog piled and this is a method to remove the attacker(s)?

Comment: @MivaScott You're ahead of me; I'm not sure I understand the intent. `:-)` I think the idea is for the caster to cause the line to emanate so that it covers enemies that are *on the ground* then the caster chooses *up* as the line's wind direction, lifting those enemies into the air (to paraphrase the question). Again, I'm just assuming, but if I'm correct, answers need not address how this kind of wind "wall" would *also* affect creatures who were leaping, flying, falling, or in gaseous form unless the answer wants to be *really* complete. Let's hope the asker revisits this soon.

Comment: If you could add a picture or drawing of what this scenario looks like that would probably help a lot. Right now I'm unsure what exact orientation the spell is taking and whether the enemy is on the ground adjacent to the caster or somewhere else entirely

Comment: @Medix2 Yeah, either `C→→→→→→` or `C↑↑↑↑↑↑` where `C` is the caster, the arrows are the *gust of wind* line, and the direction of the arrows is the wind direction. That'd be enough.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. That's precisely what I meant. The creature is adjacent to the caster on the ground,. I understand they would have to be very close to the caster, but the way @Hey I Can Chan explained the situation is what I was proposing.

Comment: *Please* edit the question to clarify. You're more than welcome to copy my ASCII so-called art if that illustrates your point, but it also sounds like the second piece of art isn't really doing your imagination justice. (I don't know why the caster would need to be close if the second piece is accurate, for example; it show the possibility of a caster hurling upward an earthbound foe that's as far as 60 ft. away from the caster.)

Answer (score 0):

### Up is a valid direction

It’s almost certainly not what the author of the spell intended, but nothing in it says you can’t do that.

### It’s not very useful under most circumstances

Keep in mind that the spells origin is *you*, so if you direct it upwards it will only affect things that are more or less directly above you. Under normal circumstances, this would then only affect creatures who are flying or under the effect of a *Levitate* spell or similar. It can not be used to lift someone off the ground unless you were in rather unusual circumstances that the rules don’t really account for (such as them standing on a grate right above you).

Answer (score -1):

**RAW, *gust of wind* does not need someone present.**

First part of the spell description.

> A line of strong wind 60 feet long and 10 feet wide blasts from you in a direction you choose for the spell’s duration.

You can do this even if there is no one present you are aware of. The only restrictions are the dimensions of the line and that you must be at the origin. Without wanting to surmise intentions, it seems that the spell was developed with ground parallel lines in mind. But restricting it from making lines with a *z* (up) component cannot be justified from RAW. As an aside, the spell does not explain either how the wind interacts with obstacles. GM's discretion is necessary in these cases.

**Creatures take fall damage if they fall to the ground.**

The falling rules in the PHB (p.183) are rather sparse:

> A fall from a great height is one of the most common hazards facing an adventurer. At the end of a fall, a creature takes 1d6 bludgeoning damage for every 10 feet it fell, to a maximum of 20d6. The creature lands prone, unless it avoids taking damage from the fall.

When a creature already falls it will not be able to start its turn above you in the air. There are **optional** falling rules in Xanathar's guide to everything (p. 77) suggesting that for very high falling distances, a drop of 500 feet per turn can be used (this happens at the end of a turn). With these rules, a creature can fall 500 feet into the spell but not to the ground. In that case, RAW they would be affected by *gust of wind* at the start of their next turn. The effect is irrelevant though. Falling does not cost movement and if someone falls more than 500 feet they will take maximum damage (20d6) anyway.

**Flying creatures are affected and will be potentially slowed but won't just fall.**

If a flying creature starts above you in your spell pointed straight up, they will be pushed further up and flying down again **in the line** costs double the movement. They can however leave the line to the side and fly down somewhere else which will cost less movement. Flying creatures will not fall down because of the spell, however. The optional falling rules in Xanathar's guide to everything (p.77) state that a

> A flying creature in flight falls if it is knocked prone, if its speed is reduced to 0 feet, or if it otherwise looses its ability to move, unless it can hover or it is being held aloft by magic, such as the *fly* spell.

None of these conditions apply.

**Creature standing on a grid might be pushed up and take fall damage.**

Now we have to consider the interaction with obstacles. This is not determined in the spell's rules so the GM decides. They could decide that if you are standing under a metal grid, for example, and someone else is standing on it, that other creature is pushed up, falls down and takes 1d6 falling damage.

**Creatures might take fall damage when pushed while standing on an elevated position.**

Finally, we consider diagonal lines, i.e. that have a z component but do not go straight up. If this causes a creature to be in the line they are pushed.

> Each creature that starts its turn in the line must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be pushed 15 feet away from you in a direction following the line.

The rules are not very clear. A direction following the line is either the line itself or it's projection on the ground. In the first case, someone will get pushed up and take fall damage if they fall at least 10 feet after. The drop depends on the angle of the line (i.e. on the ratio of the horizontal and vertical components). In either case, a creature can fall and take fall damage, if they are pushed over the edge of whatever they are standing on.